# Injecting an IEnumerable into a constructor with a Ninject factory method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to inject an `IEnumerable` into a constructor with Ninject.

My constructor looks like this:

```
public MatrixViewModel(IEnumerable<FooViewModel> fooViewModels)
{
    _fooViewModels = fooViewModels;
}
```

My Ninject module looks like this:

```
public class MainModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IEnumerable<FooViewModel>>()
            .ToMethod(context => GetFooViewModels())
            .InSingletonScope(); // this binding is not working
    }

    private IEnumerable<FooViewModel> GetFooViewModels()
    {
        // returns a bunch of foo view models
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I don't get any error. Ninject just doesn't ever use the binding, and the value that is passed into the constructor is basically just an empty default value.

How do you inject an `IEnumerable` with Ninject?

**Edit**

More details on my factory method:

```
private IEnumerable<FooViewModel> GetFooViewModels()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new FooViewModel
        {
            Bar = new BarViewModel
            {
                X = 1,
                Y = 2
            },
            Misc = "Hello"
        },
        new FooViewModel
        {
            Bar = new BarViewModel
            {
                X = 3,
                Y = 4
            },
            Misc = "Goodbye"
        },
        // etc.....
    };
}
```

**Edit 2**

Based on Remo's answer, one possible solution is to use a foreach loop to bind the view models one at a time:

```
foreach (var fooViewModel in GetFooViewModels())
{
    Bind<FooViewModel>().ToConstant(fooViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure collection support or `ToMethod` works that way.  This should would work though: `Bind<MatrixViewModel>().ToMethod(context => new MatrixViewModel(GetFooViewModels()))`.  Also, you can add your own answer to your question and accept it if Remo's wasn't quite to the level you wanted to accept as an answer.

Comment: @Merlyn, that's a good point...just "go up a level" and bind the whole MatrixViewModel (my real view model has a few parameters though, so it would be a bit more work to bind the whole thing). As for why I didn't put my solution into an answer, I could ask you the same thing about your comment :)

Comment: True :)  There are definitely multiple valid solutions to this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Remo's answer, one possible solution is to use a `foreach` loop to bind the view models one at a time:

```
foreach (var fooViewModel in GetFooViewModels())
{
    Bind<FooViewModel>().ToConstant(fooViewModel);
}
```

Comment: This should be doing the same as the original binding except that GetFooViewModels() is called at the time when the bindings are created and in the original binding it is called when it is resolved the first time.

Comment: Remo, the other difference from my original binding is that this one actually works :) But thank you for the followup.

Comment: @Remo: I got the impression that NInject special-cased collections, so it would resolve all bindings of the type in the collection.  And if it special cases it, I wouldn't be surprised if it *didn't* resolve the other way.  The behavior in the OP seems to match my assumption.  https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection

Answer (score 18):

Enumerables are treated differently by Ninject. Just provide bindings for all the view models. For enumerables Ninject will create an instance of every applying binding and pass them as `IEnumerable`.

e.g.

```
Bind<FooViewModel>().To<FooViewModel1>();
Bind<FooViewModel>().To<FooViewModel2>();
```

Comment: Remo, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really address my situation. My factory method returns a bunch of instances of FooViewModel, not a bunch of objects that inherit from FooViewModel.

Comment: Currently you can't use bindings for IEnumerable, IList, List and arrays because they are handled specially. Unfortunately you have to workaraound a bit using either an ICollection or deriving your own interface from IEnumerable<FooViewModel>

Comment: Remo, thanks and +1. I think I figured out a way to get it to work without deriving my own interface (see my Edit 2). Could you leave a comment to confirm that my solution will work reliably? Thanks.

Comment: Remo, I decided to put this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

From your question:

```
Bind<IEnumerable<FooViewModel>>()
    .ToMethod(context => GetFooViewModels())
```

I am not sure collection support or ToMethod works that way.

This should would work though:

```
Bind<MatrixViewModel>()
    .ToMethod(context => new MatrixViewModel(GetFooViewModels()))
```

Of course, how useful this solution is depends on how you're building up your views.

Comment: You're injecting into your view model, so this doesn't apply to your situation.  But if you're using WPF/MVVM, and trying to inject the view model into the view, I like remove any concept of view models from my view, and just setting the view's `DataContext` in `ToMethod`.