# How should I test this?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, ninject

I have a ViewModel, which when initialized, creates a list of objects. These objects are created by resolving interface implementation from IoC.

**ViewModel**

```
    public class ApplianceViewModel : IAppliance
    {
        private List<IHardware> HardwareItems {get; set;}

        public ApplianceViewModel()
        {
            HardwareItems = new List<IHardware>();
            var hardware1 = Constants.Kernel.Get<IHardware>();
            var hardware2 = Constants.Kernel.Get<IHardware>();

            HardwareItems.Add(hardware1);
            HardwareItems.Add(hardware2);           
        }
    }
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestClass]
public class ApplicanceViewModelTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSomething()
    {
        //Arrange
        var appliance = new ApplianceViewModel(); //This would fail to construct

    }
}
```

The above initialization would fail as the `kernel` would be null. Basically, it tells me that having a constant class and accessing kernel directly is a bad design.

But then how would I modify my `viewmodel`'s constructor so that I can initialize a list, in other words make it testable?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use IoC with DI instead of [service locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)?

Comment: @SomeUser: Yes, I think ServiceLocator pattern was what hurting me but the question in my mind was how to re-write it? Then I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816769/injecting-an-ienumerable-into-a-constructor-with-a-ninject-factory-method), which I think would resolve the problem I am having.

Answer (score 1):

> But then how would I modify my viewmodel's constructor so that I can initialize a list, in other words make it testable?

You inject it with implementations of the IHardware interface:

```
public class ApplianceViewModel : IAppliance
{
    private List<IHardware> HardwareItems {get; set;}

    public ApplianceViewModel(IHardware hardware1, Hardware hardware2)
    {
        HardwareItems = new List<IHardware>();
        var hardware1 = hardware1;
        var hardware2 = hardware2;

        HardwareItems.Add(hardware1);
        HardwareItems.Add(hardware2);           
    }
}
```

So at runtime you could inject the view model with your existing constants:

```
var appliance = new ApplianceViewModel(Constants.Kernel.Get<IHardware>(), Constants.Kernel.Get<IHardware>());
```

...and in your unit test project you pass in some other implemenation of the same interface:

```
IHardware testHardware = new TestHardware();
var appliance = new ApplianceViewModel(testHardware, testHardware);
```

You will need to implement this "TestHardware" class in a way that makes your test pass. Using a mocking framework will be useful. Please refer to the following link for more information about this: http://codetunnel.io/what-is-a-mocking-framework-why-is-it-useful/

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. I kind of knew what to do but not how to do it. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816769/injecting-an-ienumerable-into-a-constructor-with-a-ninject-factory-method) would take to me what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another interface, i.e. `IHardwareStuff`, that will return a list of `IHardware` objects. The `IHardwareStuff` gets passed as an argument into the constructor of your ViewModel. It's resolved by the dependency injection container and you can input a test implementation when you want to.

By doing this separation, you split your object into a *value object* and a *service object*. The first one you create by doing `new` and passing some concrete values to it. The latter is created by the dependency injection container and doesn't have concrete values passed into it as a constructor.

You can than write unit tests for both objects.

Answer (score 0):

For a good and testable design it's better if constructors do nothing, validation or variable assignment.

I suggesto to inject in the constructor of `ApplianceViewModel` the list `HardwareItems`.